# For studying Catalyst

Tags: perl, catalyst

I want to study catalyst MVC freamwork for perl but I don't have any idea about 
catalyst or MVC freamwork so. from where I have to start..?? can you suggest me a book for that related topics which best.

Comment: Start with the official [catalyst web site](http://www.catalystframework.org/), and the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Catalyst-Manual/lib/Catalyst/Manual.pm).

Answer (score 6):

The [Catalyst::Manual](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst::Manual::Intro) distribution contains complete and thorough documentation for Catalyst, including a [lengthy tutorial](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst::Manual::Tutorial) and a [cookbook](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst::Manual::Cookbook).

Answer (score 3):

[The Definitive Guide to Catalyst](http://books.google.com.au/books/about/Catalyst.html?id=OvD7Loxt8vwC) is an extremely good book, and covers Model-View-Controller design quite well. The official [Tutorial](http://search.cpan.org/~hkclark/Catalyst-Manual-5.9002/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Tutorial.pod) is also very worthwhile for coming to grips with Catalyst.

[image: Definitive Guide to Catalyst]